# sample to create a html page with a language translator using c#

Tags: c#, .net

How can i create a simple aspx page with a dropdown have two enteries
1. Translate to greek
2. Translae to english

I'll be getting the data from a db table which is in English. While choosing the items from the dropdown the text should change accordingly. How an I achieve this ?
code snippets would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are storing only the English version of your site in the database you will need some language translation API. Google provides such service: it's called the [Google AJAX Language API](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/) and allows you to translate text between different languages. Here's a [sample in C#](http://vincenthomedev.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/calling-google-ajax-language-api-in-c-net/) of how it could be used.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Microsoft's Translator Widget](http://www.microsofttranslator.com/widget/)

It does what you want (if I've read your post correctly and understand what you're after) pretty easily!